# erro Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined com vue.js

Tags: vue.js

OBS:Por favor, gostaria que não me notificassem negativamente por essa postagem, pois ela tem semelhança com uma outra postagem feita recentemente, esse é um problema especifico.

[Clica no meu Vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0R5LU5C8Xo&feature=youtu.be)

Estou tentando refatorar meu layout usando `vue.js`, ou seja, é um tipo de reaproveitamento de código, exemplo! Estou com uma pagina principal e gostaria de aproveitar o menu que foi construído nela numa pagina secundária, em vez de ficar duplicando código, eu simplesmente crio uma ponte para referencia um código que já existe na pagina secundária, e automaticamente ele incorporar um código já construído na pagina principal.

Veja como está a estrutura do meu projeto, ele foi feito no editor `atom`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode perceber que criei a pagina principal dentro da pasta layout com o nome de `base.vue` e a próxima etapa seria referencia-la na pagina secundária, porém o método não é reconhecido pelo `vue.js` e gostaria de saber porque isso está acontecendo.

```
components: {
       VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),

    },
```

Eu sei disso porque tentei subir a aplicação no meu servidor local e quando fui visualizar a pagina não apareceu nada, quando fui inspecionar a pagina no consoles do Google Chrome ele me retornou esse erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está dizendo é que não foi localizado o `VLayout` no projeto.

Mas como pode não conseguir localizar o método está na pagina secundária e a pagina principal existe no local correto?

aceito sugestões!

Essa é minha pagina `base.vue` está dentro da pasta layout;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-header>
      <v-toolbar>
        <v-nav-icon @click.native="toggleDrawer" />
        <v-toolbar-title>Music DB</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-toolbar-actions>
          <v-toolbar-action>
            <v-icon>exit_to_app</v-icon>
          </v-toolbar-action>
        </v-toolbar-actions>
      </v-toolbar>
      <transition name="slide-left">
        <v-drawer v-if="drawerActive">
          <v-drawer-header>
            <v-nav-icon
              variant="green"
              @click.native="toggleDrawer"
            />
            <v-drawer-title>Music DB</v-drawer-title>
          </v-drawer-header>
          <v-drawer-body>
            <v-navigation>
              <v-navigation-item>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'artists.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Artists</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'albums.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Albums</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
                <v-navigation-link :route="{ name: 'songs.index' }">
                  <v-navigation-content>Songs</v-navigation-content>
                </v-navigation-link>
              </v-navigation-item>
            </v-navigation>
          </v-drawer-body>
          <v-drawer-footer>For educational purposes only</v-drawer-footer>
        </v-drawer>
      </transition>
    </v-header>
    <v-content>
      <!-- The content of the page will be placed here -->
      <slot></slot>
    </v-content>
    <transition name="fade">
      <v-overlay
        v-show="drawerActive"
        @click.native="hideDrawer"
      />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    /**
     * The name of the layout.
     */
    name: 'base-layout',

    data() {
      return {
        drawerActive: false,
      };
    },

    /**
     * The methods which the layout can use.
     */
    methods: {
      /**
       * Method used to hide the drawer.
       */
      hideDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = false;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to toggle the drawer.
       */
      toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

essa é minha pagina `index`

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
      <v-grid variant="container">
        <v-row variant="xs-center">
          <v-col :variants="['xs-9', 'md-4', 'lg-3']">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-body>
                <v-form @submit.prevent.native="setQuery(query)">
                  <v-input-group>
                    <v-icon variant="signifier">search</v-icon>
                    <v-text-field
                      variant="with-signifier"
                      v-model="query"
                      placeholder="Find artist"
                    />
                  </v-input-group>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-body>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col :variants="['xs-3', 'md-4', 'lg-3', 'md-offset-4', 'lg-offset-6']">
            <v-button
              variant="circle" class="pull-right"
              @click.native="redirectToCreatePage"
            >
              <v-icon>add</v-icon>
            </v-button>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col variant="sm">
            <v-table>
              <v-table-header>
                <v-table-row>
                  <v-table-head>Name</v-table-head>
                  <v-table-head>Birthday</v-table-head>
                </v-table-row>
              </v-table-header>
              <v-table-body>
                <v-table-row
                  v-for="artist in artist.all"
                  :key="artist"
                  variant="body"
                >
                  <v-table-cell>
                    <router-link :to="getArtistRoute(artist.id)">{{ artist.fullName }}</router-link>
                  </v-table-cell>
                  <v-table-cell>{{ artist.birthday }}</v-table-cell>
                </v-table-row>
                <v-table-row v-if="artist.all.length === 0">
                  <v-table-cell colspan="3">Artists not found...</v-table-cell>
                </v-table-row>
              </v-table-body>
            </v-table>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col variant="xs-justify">
            <v-card variant="inline">
              <v-card-body>
                <v-pagination
                  :pagination="artist.pagination"
                  :switch-page-function="setPage"
                  variant="small"
                />
              </v-card-body>
            </v-card>
            <v-card variant="inline">
              <v-card-body>
                <v-select
                  v-model="artist.pagination.limit"
                  :items="pageNumbers"
                />
              </v-card-body>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-grid>
  </v-layout>
</template>



<script>
  export default {
    /**
     * The name of the layout.
     */
    name: 'artist-index',

    data() {
      return {
        artist: {
          all: [],
          pagination: {
            totalCount: 0,
            totalPages: 0,
            currentPage: 1,
            limit: 5,
          },
        },
        drawerActive: false,
        query: null,
        pageNumbers: [
          5,
          10,
          15,
        ],
      };
    },

    /**
     * The methods which the layout can use.
     */
    methods: {
      /**
       * Method used to hide the drawer.
       */
      hideDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = false;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to toggle the drawer.
       */
      toggleDrawer() {
        this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
      },

      /**
       * Method used to get the artist route.
       *
       * @param {Number} id The artist identifier.
       *
       * @returns {Object} The artist route.
       */
      getArtistRoute() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to redirect the user to the artist create page.
       */
      redirectToCreatePage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to go to a different page.
       *
       * @param {Number} page The page number.
       */
      setPage() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the limit of the items being displayed.
       *
       * @param {Number} limit The limit of items being displayed.
       */
      setLimit() {
        // todo
      },

      /**
       * Method used to set the query of the search bar.
       * The results will be debounced using the lodash debounce method.
       */
      setQuery() {
        // todo
      },
    },

    /**
     * Available watchers for this page.
     */
    watch: {
      query(query) {
        this.setQuery(query);
      },
    },

    components: {
       VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),

    },
  };
</script>
```

=======================================================

Estou tentando dessa forma mais está dando erro! qual seria a maneira de implementar o `console.log`?

```
components: {

  const VLayout: require('@/layouts/base'),
  console.log(VLayout);

},
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que é esse `@` no caminho para o ficheiro? Se fizeres `const VLayout = require('@/layouts/base');` depois `console.log(VLayout);` o que dá?

Comment: O erro está no `base.vue`, a setinha no console sempre aponta para onde está o problema. Normalmente esse erro dá quando algum dado necessário para renderizar o componente ainda não está pronto quando o componente tenta se renderizar. Faz algum teste no `base.vue`, deixando-o mais simples,se funcionar, é só ir acrescentando os elementos a pouco que você vai detectar onde o erro está.

Comment: @LeonardoVilarinho espere um pouco que já vou tentar fazer como você me disse, mas antes vou tentar ver a orientação de Sergio

Comment: eu fiz uma alteração na minha postagem, @Sergio você poderia dá uma olhada por favor na alteração que fiz na minha postagem? está bem no finalzinho.

Comment: Podes fazer o que sugeri no comentário? fazer o require no inicio e depois `console.log(VLayout);`o que dá?

Comment: ele gera erros, você poderia por favor se não for incomodo que possas colocar uma resposta a postagem colocando como devo implementar o consoles.log   nesse método ?

Comment: @Sergio fiz uma outra atualização na minha postagem, poderia dá uma olhada por favor?

Comment: @wladyband testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/zoew4nae/

Comment: @Sergio nessa aplicação online tem como eu adicionar mais uma pagina HTML?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0R5LU5C8Xo&feature=youtu.be